# OpenGL - Using uniform variable breaks shader

Tags: opengl, shader, uniform

There's a uniform vec3 in my shader that causes some odd behavior. If I use it in any way inside the shader - even if it has no actual effect on anything - the shader breaks and nothing that uses it is rendered.

This is the (vertex) shader:

```
#version 330 core
layout(std140) uniform ViewProjection
{
    mat4 V;
    mat4 P;
};

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

smooth out vec3 UVW;

uniform mat4 M;
uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

void main()
{
    vec3 vtrans = vec3(vertexPosition_modelspace.x,vertexPosition_modelspace.y,vertexPosition_modelspace.z);

    // if(cameraPosition.y == 123456)
    // {}
    mat4 MVP = P *V *M;
    vec4 MVP_Pos = MVP *vec4(vtrans,1);
    gl_Position = MVP_Pos;

    UVW = vertexPosition_modelspace;
}
```

If I use it like this, it works fine, but as soon as I uncomment the commented lines, the shader breaks. There's no error on compiling or linking the shader, glGetError() reports no errors either. It happens if 'cameraPosition' is used in ANY way, even if it's meaningless.

This only happens on my laptop however, which is running OpenGL 3.1. On my PC with OpenGL 4.* I don't have this issue.

What's going on here?

Comment: Are you actually setting the uniform in your code?

Comment: I suspect that on this particular shader source the `if` statement gets thrown away as it essentially does nothing, so that seems indeed strange.

Comment: Also as sidenote for the `vtrans`, why don't you simply use `vec3 vtrans = vertexPosition_modelspace`? (Just curious as I am learning GLSL myself)

Comment: "The shader breaks" is extraordinarily vague. What exactly happens? Do you get any info from the compiler/linker info log? You may be doing something bad like hardcoding the location of your uniform block `ViewProjection` in your code, that is something that would "break" your GLSL program without a compile/link error.

Comment: @skiwi It doesn't do anything in this case, it's there because I need to transform it by the cameraPosition, which is where the problem comes in.

Comment: @AndonM As I've said, compiling and linking is fine, nothing in the log. By "break" I mean that nothing that uses this shader is rendered at all. As for the uniform block, I'm using glGetUniformBlockIndex(program,"ViewProjection") to retrieve the block index and glUniformBlockBinding to bind it to my binding point.

Comment: You should check if the compilation itself fails. You can force your OpenGL version on the 4.1 system back to 3.3 and see if it reproduces. Since the compilation is done by the OpenGL driver, that may be a possible cause (e.g. NV vs AMD). Also verify the text source to be ANSI in the commented lines. And if this is not your own engine code, setting the missing uniform may possibly have the shader rejected internally, but that's assuming you're using a 3rd party viz. framework/engine.